# CAMetalLayer initialization only works on main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, metal

I do have a straight forward CAMetalLayer setup, except the CAMetalLayer is initialized on a global thread, which looks like this (call init, setup basic properties and add as sublayer):

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let renderLayer = CAMetalLayer()
    renderLayer.isOpaque = false
    renderLayer.frame = frame
    renderLayer.drawableSize = drawableSize
    renderLayer.framebufferOnly = false
    renderLayer.device = metalDevice
    renderLayer.pixelFormat = metalPixelFormat
    renderLayer.contentsScale = contentScale
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        view.layer.addSublayer(renderLayer)
    }
}
```

**This code runs without any runtime errors, but unfortunately when rendering to the `CAMetalLayer` drawable there is no render output shown on the screen**. Tests show, that the `CAMetalLayer` drawable does have a proper texture (with desired size) and the data is written to it as expected, but not shown on screen.

To my surprise running the `CAMetalLayer` initialization on the main thread fixes this problem. So the following is a solution:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    var renderLayer: CAMetalLayer!
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        renderLayer = CAMetalLayer()
    }
    renderLayer.isOpaque = false
    renderLayer.frame = frame
    renderLayer.drawableSize = drawableSize
    renderLayer.framebufferOnly = false
    renderLayer.device = metalDevice
    renderLayer.pixelFormat = metalPixelFormat
    renderLayer.contentsScale = contentScale
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        view.layer.addSublayer(renderLayer)
    }
}
```

As I want to be able to run the `CAMetalLayer` creation completely on the background thread I would like to avoid calling `CAMetalLayer()` on the main thread. Also, I couldn't find any requirement for `CAMetalLayer` to be initialized on the main thread in the documentation.

**So my questions are:**

- **Is it possible to run the init `CAMetalLayer()` on a background thread and if so how?**
- **If it is not possible: why?**

Additional Info: I am using XCode 11 and running the code on iOS 13.1. I also had the same issue with XCode 10 and iOS version 12.

Comment: Excellent research! What's bad about calling just that one line on the main thread? By the way, that code is wrong: you should never call `main.sync`. Well, you can, but in general don't.

Comment: @matt: I could call that one line on the main thread, but it felt wrong for me to do so, because I could find no info on `CAMetalLayer` needing to be initialized on the main thread. I am also curious if there is really such a requirement. Also calling the one line on the main thread would be inconvenient for me because my current code would need some adjustments to avoid a deadlock on the main thread. So if I could avoid it, I would.